# Matrix dimension and set up weights and biases in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to replicate a neural network, and I try to set up weights and biases of an basic neural network by myself. However, the error of `mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (3x2 and 3x2)` occurs. Can someone help me how to fix it.

Here is the code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/153HVoOh4si_aiy2ki_kv429tHW8d5Lla#scrollTo=mmofzsOzynHu

I want it to run so that I can caculate and figure how neural network works